# How to make two fragments from one view?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a good working app. It includes Main.java, StartScreenView.java, HelpView.java and FirstView.java. And FirstView.java is a main working screen now. 
I want to change this app - to add second view (SecondView.java) on a main screen. Both could works as fragments - one in a top of screen, another in a bottom. 
Main.java has this code:

```
...
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.content.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static ...
... // some variables

// called when this Activity is first created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    main = this;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(SCREEN_WIDTH, metrics.widthPixels);
    editor.putInt(SCREEN_HEIGHT, metrics.heightPixels);
    editor.commit();

    layout = 
        (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 

        {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case FIRST_SCREEN:                      
                    gameScreen();
                    break;
                case HELP_SCREEN:
                    helpScreen();
                    break;
                case START_SCREEN:
                    startScreen();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    startScreen();
}

void startScreen()
{
    // create Start Screen View
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    layout = 
        (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    start = new StartScreenView(this, preferences, layout); 
    layout.addView(start, 0); // add view to the layout
    currentScreen = START_SCREEN;
    start.resume(this);
}

void firstScreen(int color, int level)
{

    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    layout = 
        (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    // create a new MainView and add it to the RelativeLayout
    game = new FirstView(this, getSharedPreferences(SpotOn.PREFS_TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout);
    layout.addView(first, 0); // add view to the layout
    currentScreen = FIRST_SCREEN;
    first.start(this);
}

void helpScreen()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.help);
    layout = 
        (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.helpLayout);
    // create a new MainView and add it to the RelativeLayout
    help = new HelpView(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout);
    layout.addView(help, 0); // add view to the layout
    currentScreen = HELP_SCREEN;
    help.resume(this);
}



public static void getCallBackFromView(int message)
{
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(message);
};

// called when this Activity moves to the background
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    MusicManager.pause();
    if (first != null)
        first.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (first != null)
        first.resume(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if (first != null)
        first.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    switch (currentScreen)
    {
        case FIRST_SCREEN:
            first.destroy();
            startScreen();
            break;
        case HELP_SCREEN:
            help.pause();
            startScreen();
            break;
        case START_SCREEN:
            super.onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

To make a simple application with the fragments, as they say in the lessons, you need to create two fragments in the main layout. Each of them must contain one class fragment, which should have its own layout. But in my application code is much more complicated than in the android lessons. Please tell how to make two fragments instead of one view.
I have no reputation, can not post images. See the scheme below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
!                          now                              !
! ----------------------------  --------------------------- !
! !                          !  !                          !!
! !                          !  !                          !!
! !  ---------------------!  !  !                          !!
! !  !                    !  !  !                          !!
! !  !    First (button)  !  !  !                          !!
! !  !--------------------!  !  !                          !!
! !                          !  !                          !!
! !  !--------------------!  !  !                          !!
! !  !    Help  (button)  !  !  !                          !!
! !  !--------------------!  !  !                          !!
! !                          !  !                          !!
! !                          !  !                          !!
! !                          !  !                          !!
! !   StartView.java         !  !  FirstScreen.java        !!
! !                          !  !                          !!
! ----------------------------  --------------------------- !
!                          must be                          ! 
! ----------------------------  ---------------------------!!
! !                          !  !!------------------------!!!
! !                          !  !!                        !!!
! !                          !  !!                        !!!
! !                          !  !!                        !!!
! !  ---------------------!  !  !!                        !!!
! !  !                    !  !  !! FirstScreen.java       !!!
! !  !    First? (button) !  !  !!------------------------!!!
! !  !--------------------!  !  !                          !!
! !                          !  !!------------------------!!!
! !  !--------------------!  !  !!                        !!!
! !  !    Help   (button) !  !  !!                        !!!
! !  !--------------------!  !  !!                        !!!
! !                          !  !!                        !!!
! !   StartView.java         !  !! SecondScreen.java      !!!
! !                          !  !!------------------------!!!
! ----------------------------  ---------------------------!!
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you currently have the FirstScreen view you could create 2 containers for the fragments you will add (or add the fragments in the layout directly).

For example, you could add 2 FrameLayouts, firstViewContainer and secondViewContainer. 
Then, in the activity  you would create your fragments and add them to the containers.

```
FirstViewFragment first = FirstViewFragment.getInstance();
SecondViewFragment second = SecondViewFragment.getInstance();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.firstViewContainer, first);
ft.replace(R.id.secondViewContainter, second);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: I tried to do this variant. But Eclipse underline (not accept) words 'Fragment1' and 'Fragment2':  `public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
if (savedInstanceState == null) {   
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_1, Fragment1, null).add(R.id.fragment_2, Fragment2, null).commit();       }   
}    
} `

Comment: You have to instantiate the fragments before you use them.